# How do I turn a Tensorflow Dataset into a Numpy Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'm interested in a Tensorflow Dataset, but I want to manipulate it using `numpy`. Is it possible to turn this `PrefetchDataset` into an array?

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

dataset = tfds.load('mnist')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify `split` or `as_supervised`, `tfds` will return a dictionary with `train` and `test` set. Since `as_supervised` defaults to `False`, the `image` and `label` will also be separate in a dictionary. This is what it will look like:

```
{'test': <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (28, 28, 1), label: ()}, 
    types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>,
 'train': <PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (28, 28, 1), label: ()}, 
    types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>}
```

So here's how you can turn it into a `numpy` array:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

dataset = tfds.load('mnist')

train, test = dataset['train'], dataset['test']

train_numpy = np.vstack(tfds.as_numpy(train))
test_numpy = np.vstack(tfds.as_numpy(test))

X_train = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[0]['image'], train_numpy)))
y_train = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[0]['label'], train_numpy)))

X_test = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[0]['image'], test_numpy)))
y_test = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[0]['label'], test_numpy)))
```

You might want to set `as_supervised=True`, which will return `tuple` instead of a dictionary for `image` and `label`.

```
[<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((28, 28, 1), ()), types: (tf.uint8, tf.int64)>]
```

In this case, you will need to select the 'image' and 'label' using indexing like `[0]`. So here's how you can turn it into a `numpy` array:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

dataset = tfds.load('mnist', split=['test'], as_supervised=True)

array = np.vstack(tfds.as_numpy(dataset[0]))

X_train = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[0], array)))
y_train = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[1], array)))
```

Proof:

```
X_train.shape
```

```
(10000, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: What is the importance of np.vstack? I tried just tfds.as_numpy and it outputs the same results since the former one will be depreciated in the longer term.